# jquery prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, prototype-programming

I am using the following boilerplate to try something out:
https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.prototypal-inheritance.plugin-boilerplate.js

So if "myObject" would be named "car", how do I extend the whole thing with another class then, something like a car type e.g. "bmw" (main class "car", subclass "bmw")

Don't I have to change "$.plugin = function( name, object )" to "$.plugin = function( name, object, extend )" and apply the subclass to it? It's a bit unfortunate that they haven't written a full example of a prototypal inheritance. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: btw: you are not settings the `brand` as a property of the instance, youre just declaring a variable

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0oLgpjbq/3/

Comment: hahahaha.. @Alex, you just stole my example, but it is not valid in this case. When I look at your edits I see you don't get it. It was to show how the Revealing module pattern is working. FYI: http://jsfiddle.net/0oLgpjbq/ The edited code is a perfect example of bad practice.

Comment: The jsfiddle code examples do not make much sense to me. Because the plugins should be separated, and not in a single class / object (or function, just like in the jsfiddle example). To be more clear, if I have a own file for each plugin (like pluginMain.js, pluginSub1.js, pluginSub2.js, etc.), then pluginSub can't be inherited from pluginMain. So in which way should I rewrite this jQuery Boilerplate to get the result of fully inherited subclasses / subplugins?

Comment: I took a quick look at the boilerplate but couldn't figure it out(within a sec) how it exactly works. Why won't you mix plain JavaScript(ECMAScript) and jQuery like this fiddle I created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/cbv7reyo/ ? Ps. take a look at require.js. This is ideal to integrate asynchronous loading.